# If ( number < 0 )

Tags: php

Hey can someone help me why the following code doesn't work?

```
<?php  if($stats['profit'] < 0) { ?>
    <td class="profit" style="padding-left:10px;color:#17D700">$<?=$stats['profit'];?></td>
    <?php   } ?>
<?php else {    ?>
    <td class="profit" style="padding-left:10px;color:black">$<?=$stats['profit'];?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: More code would be helpful

Comment: Do explain what you need to get solved and what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Try this:

```
<?php  if ($stats['profit'] < 0) : ?>
    <td class="profit" style="padding-left:10px;color:#17D700">$<?=$stats['profit']; ?></td>
<?php else : ?>
    <td class="profit" style="padding-left:10px;color:black">$<?=$stats['profit']; ?></td>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[Alternative else/if control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

If you want you can use the ternary `if` operator in a single line:

```
<td class="profit" style="padding-left:10px;color:#<?php echo (($stats['profit'] < 0) ?'17D700':'000000') ?>">$<?=$stats['profit'];?></td>
```

Comment: Nice. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are after the *echo* function. In which case the statements within the td tags would be, `<?php echo $stats['profit']; ?>`. Let me know if this was useful.

Comment: In fact, that has same effect as `<?=`. The question is about something else (although not clear at all).

Comment: I've never come across that syntax before so thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea. I´ve never used the structure "**< ? =**" may be is possible but it is not familiar for me.

```
<?php  if($stats['profit'] < 0) { ?>
     <td class="profit" style="padding-left:10px;color:#17D700">$<?php $stats['profit'];?></td>
  <?php } else { ?>
     <td class="profit" style="padding-left:10px;color:black">$<?php $stats['profit'];?></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Another option (php pure)

```
<?php 
  $format = ($stats['profit'] < 0 ? 'padding-left:10px;style="color: #17D700;"' : 'padding-left:10px;style="color: black;"' );
  echo "<td ".$format.">$".$stats['profit']."</td>"
?>
```

I hope it fits for you.